# How to include related model fields in elastic search document using django-elastic-search-dsl-drf

Tags: python-3.x, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf, I have two models called Parent and Child where the child model has Foreign key relation with the Parent model

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

I want to perform a full-text search on the Parent model including the fields in its related model(Child).
I have created a Parent document and I'm able to perform a search on parent model fields but I'm unable to figure out how to include related model fields in the parent document.

Comment: Please mind the capitalization of personal pronouns, and the stylizing of tech names.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this link](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#handle-relationship-with-nestedfield-objectfield)

The link provided is from the `django-elasticsearch-dsl` package, which is used by `django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf`. The example given shows in detail how to create a Document for a model that has BOTH foreign keys AND related models.

One cool feature I want to point out is this:

```
related_models = [Manufacturer, Ad]  # Optional: to ensure the Car will be re-saved when Manufacturer or Ad is updated
```